# PHP symfony learning and upgrading

Tags: symfony, symfony1

I have to learn symfony to work on application that was built on Symfony 1 , I suppose to learn symfony 1 then upgrade the system to symfony2 , Is their any thought about the best practice that I can follow to learn symfony 1 and upgrade the system to symfony 2 in an efficient way ?

Comment: Symfony2 is totally different from Symfony1, I recommend you start with version 2 or 3.

Comment: Do not, I repeat, do not, deliberately create a symfony 1 project with the intention of upgrading it to symfony 2/3. This is like purchasing a mountain bike with the intention of upgrading it to a jet ski.

Comment: It was built 5 years ago , So this isn't my choice.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much digging you've already done, but the Symfony1 legacy docs are all available here:

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction

There is a cookbook article that covers a lot of the differences between Symfony1 and newer Symfony2 here:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/symfony1.html (That's the last version of that doc apparently).

However, it really depends on the size of the application and your general familiarity with newer Symfony or other frameworks for what you should be doing next. It might be more worthwhile to work on just rewriting it in a more modern framework at this point and using the existing application as a starting point for functionality/features needed.